# Python Shell Script returns error to Flask/SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kuyrL6krkwA. I have modified the db, table, and columns names for my app. Everything else is identical to tutorial. The error occurs (10 mins into tutorial) where he enters python shell and runs the following commands:

```
from models import User   # my app uses 'User' not 'BlogPost'
users = User.query.all()
```

The Python Shell Script returns error message below:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such
column:users.id u'SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.name AS
users_name, users.zipcode AS users_zipcode, users.inter1 AS
users_inter1, users.inter2 AS users_inter2, users.inter3 AS
users_inter3 \nFROM users' ()
```

The three files I am using are (App.py, models.py, db_create.py)

App.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///mfiyzc.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run(debug = True)
```

models.py

```
from app import db
class User(db.Model):

  __tablename__ = "users"

   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
   zipcode = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
   inter1 = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
   inter2 = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
   inter3 = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

   def __init__(self, name, zipcode, inter1, inter2, inter3):
       self.name = name
       self.zipcode = zipcode
       self.inter1 = inter1
       self.inter2 = inter2
       self.inter3 = inter3

   def __repr__(self):
       return '<title {}'.format(self.title)
```

db_create.py

```
from app import db
from models import User

db.create_all()

db.session.add(User("Jane Parker", 11104, "ice skating", "dancing", "reading"))
db.session.add(User("Bob Smith", 11104, "boxing", "cars", "beers"))

db.session.commit()
```

Comment: What is the output of `.schema users` in sqlite?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run db_create.py ie :

> python db_create.py

or

```
from models import User
db.create_all()
```

You are trying to query the table before it has been created.

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong field name (since I copied from the tutorial)

incorrect:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '<title {}'.format(self.title)
```

correct:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '<name {}'.format(self.name)
```